# Mistake about Covariance on Wikipedia Page for Leverage?

Tags: covariance-matrix, leverage

Wikipedia's page for [leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)) defines the design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ where $n$ is the number of data and $p$ is the dimensionality of each datum, and then, under "Relation to Mahalanobis distance", defines $S := X^T X$ and states that $S$ is the "estimated covariance matrix."

I thought that in order for $S$ to be a covariance matrix, we need to (1) de-mean $X$ and (2) divide by the number of data (or potentially the number of data - 1).

Is that not the case? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are correct and that passage is wrong.

Comment: I see this claim (that $X^T X$ is the empiric covariance) all over the place (including on this site). Where does this misconception arise from? Is there an implicit convention that the design matrix is always centered?

Comment: Yes.  There appear to be some communities, often related to signal processing, that assume data have zero means and, often, that they have unit variances.  This is *not* standard in statistics due to the need to deal with all kinds of data and models where those restrictive assumptions will be violated.

Comment: Thank you! If I can ask one quick question (not worth opening a separate question), is there a term for the Mahalanobis distance using not the covariance matrix but instead using the second moment matrix?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that one.  A little research turns up a interesting paper by del Pino & Galaz (1995), https://www.jstor.org/stable/43601459, who call it the "inverse Gram matrix" and present several statistical applications and interpretations.