# Proof that leverage points are between 0 and 1 inclusive

Tags: leverage, projection

I would really appreciate it if anyone can guide me through this.
I have a $n \times (p+1)$ matrix $X$. The projection matrix $P = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. I want to prove that $P(i,i)$ is in $[0,1]$, where $P(i,i)$ is a leverage point. How can I prove it using the idempotent property of the projection matrix. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: $1-P$ is a projection matrix, too.  Thus, all you need show is that diagonal elements of projection matrices are non-negative.

Comment: You can answer yourself from the algebra at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212656/leverages-and-effect-of-leverage-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I - P$ is also idempotent, i.e., $I - P = (I - P)'$ and $(I - P)^2 = I - P$.

Let $e_i$ be the $n$-vector with the $i$-th entry $1$ and all the other entries $0$, then
\begin{align}
P_{ii} &= e_i'Pe_i = e_i'PPe_i = e_i'P'Pe_i = (Pe_i)'(Pe_i) \geq 0, \\
1 - P_{ii} &= e_i'(I - P)e_i = e_i'(I - P)(I - P)e_i = e_i'(I - P)'(I - P)e_i \\
& = 
((I - P)e_i)'((I - P)e_i) \geq 0,
\end{align}
which shows $0 \leq P_{ii} \leq 1$.

---

It is worth pointing out that given $X$ contains the intercept term, $P_{ii}$ actually has a tighter lower bound $n^{-1}$, but the proof is more involved (check [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61924/diagonal-elements-of-the-projection-matrix)).

Comment: +1.  You only need the first line of your three-line calculation, because it shows generally that $P_{ii}\ge 0$ for any projection matrix.  Since $1-P$ is a projection matrix and $(1-P)_{ii} = 1-P_{ii},$ you know without further calculation that $1-P_{ii} \ge 0,$ so you're done.