# How do we prove that the rows or columns of a hat matrix sum up to 1, when mean function includes an intercept?

Tags: regression, matrix, projection

Every textbook I encounter tells me that this is simply a meaningful relationship of a hat matrix, without explaining why:

If H is the hat (projection) matrix, and our X matrix has full rank and a leading column of 1s, then:

∑ of i from (1 to n) H[ij] = 1
and
∑ of j from (1 to n) H[ij] = 1

In other words, the sum of any row or column of the hat matrix is 1.  This is listed repeatedly in texts I have read, but its never shown how we actually know this.

Additionally, I'd like to know why the lower bound of any given H[ii] value is 1/n, where n is the number of observations in the matrix X.  This is also not explained.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the name of the book or at least a link?

Comment: Applied Linear Regression 4th edition, by Sanford Weisberg, for one.

Comment: I've literally never seen a proof (before I wrote this) but the row and columns sums thing is obvious. $HX = X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top X = X$.

Now the first column of $X$ is $1$'s and  the first column of $HX$ is $1$'s

Hence the sum of each row of $H$ is $1$.

$H$ is symmetric, so the sum of each column is 1 (though there's other ways to show it, such as looking at $X^\top H$.

Comment: Why does the first column of HX being 1s make the rows of H total to one?

Comment: Shebb: I googled and found below. I think the answer is in there ( atleast to the 1/n part of the question ). As far as the summing to one, that may be hidden in there too. It's all too complex for me to read, atleast at this hour of my brain cycle. Good luck. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61924/diagonal-elements-of-the-projection-matrix

Comment: @Shebb because of how matrix multiplication works? You need to think for a moment about what is happening when you compute HX. Start with the first element. The (1,1) element of HX is the sum of (the first row of H) times (the first column of X). Since the first column of X is all 1's, this is the sum of the first row of H. Now since HX=X, the (1,1) element of HX is 1. Similarly for the (2,1) element, the (3,1) element and so forth ...

Comment: Thanks Glen_b. Shebb, if you read Glen_b's latest explanation carefully, you can avoid any confusion by not going to the link that I sent. On the other hand, it may help for the 1/n part of the question. All the best.

Comment: Since $H$ is a symmetric projection matrix that preserves $X,$ simply consider what $HX=X$ means for the first column of $X.$  (The symmetry implies the same result for rows.)

Comment: The questions you have been asking have been answered elsewhere here on CV.  To illustrate how to find them, here is the [search I used to find the duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hat+matrix+1%2Fn).